# Coldfusion HQL query with relationships - unable to resolve path

Tags: orm, coldfusion, hql, entity-relationship, railo

I'm having problems using an HQL query to get data from a related entity.

I have a 'Photoshoot' entity with a one to many relationship to an 'Image' entity.
I'm trying to pull all images that belong to a particular Photoshoot, which I want to do with an HQL query so that I can get some specific filtering in.

What I'm getting back is this:
Unable to resolve path [Photoshoot.sPhotoshootGUID], unexpected token [Photoshoot] [FROM Image WHERE Photoshoot.sPhotoshootGUID = '889440aa-a12a-11e1-8edb-d02788828044']

I can't figure out why - if I pull back the Photoshoot, I can easily get to the associated images using the 'getImages()' function. If I use exactly the same code to get another related entity it seems to work fine!

Here's the code for my entities:

--- Image ---

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" entityname="Image" table="tblImages_Base">
<!--- Identifier --->
<cfproperty name="sImageGUID" fieldtype="id" generator="guid" setter="false" />

<!--- Properties --->
<cfproperty name="sFileName" ormtype="string" />
<cfproperty name="sImageFolder" ormtype="string" dbdefault="" />

<cfproperty name="Active" ormtype="boolean" default=0 dbdefault=0 notnull="true" />

<!--- Many Images can belong to a single Photoshoot --->
<cfproperty name="Photoshoot" 
            fieldtype="many-to-one" 
            cfc="Photoshoot" 
            fkcolumn="fk_sPhotoshootGUID" 
            fetch="join"
            inverse="true"             
            />
</cfcomponent>
```

--- Photoshoot ---

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" entityname="Photoshoot" table="tblPhotoshoots">
<!--- Identifier --->
<cfproperty name="sPhotoshootGUID" fieldtype="id" generator="guid" setter="false" />

<!--- Properties --->
<cfproperty name="Active" ormtype="boolean" default=0 dbdefault=0 notnull="true" />
<cfproperty name="l_ImageOrder" ormtype="text" />

<!--- One Photoshoot can contain many Images --->
<cfproperty name="Images" 
            fieldtype="one-to-many" 
            cfc="Image" 
            fkcolumn="fk_sPhotoshootGUID" 
            type="array" 
            singularname="Image"
            />
</cfcomponent>
```

--- HQL Query ---

```
<cfquery name="Local.objPhotoshootImages" dbtype="hql">
    FROM    Image
    WHERE   Photoshoot.sPhotoshootGUID = '889440aa-a12a-11e1-8edb-d02788828044' 
</cfquery>
```

If it makes a difference, I'm running on Railo 3.3.3.000

Comment: Have you tried scoping Photoshoot as it's possibly ambiguous. 'from Image img where img.Photoshoot.sPhotoshootGuid =... '

Comment: Gave that a go but got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your HQL is failing - that error can be due to case-sensitivity, but "Photoshoot" seems to be in the correct case in the code you've posted.

As a workaround you could try adjusting your HQL to make the join explicit:

```
<cfquery name="Local.objPhotoshootImages" dbtype="hql">
FROM    Image
WHERE   fk_sPhotoshootGUID = '889440aa-a12a-11e1-8edb-d02788828044'
</cfquery>
```